# JavaScript seating chart library

Tags: library, javascript, user-interface, floor-plan

I'm creating a web app for selling online tickets. Where the user will be able to design a seating chart. Each seating chart has a collection of seats. These seats can be assigned unique numbers or names. You can organize seats into larger groups, such as rows, sections, or levels. In other words, the user will be able to design their layout.

What can be used in the front end for the user to design the layout? Is there some JavaScript library (ideally open source) that could help me?

It will look more or less like this:

[image: Graphic showing seats in differently colored groups]

Comment: Does this need to be free or can it be commercial?

Answer (score 3):

One that I know of is called, "jQuery Seat Charts". It's open source available on GitHub and provides an easy way to create/design seat charts available in webpages. It creates a map along with a legend proving an easy interface for any user to choose the seats that they want.

## [jQuery Seat Charts](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts) (open source)

> jQuery Seat Charts (JSC) is a full-blown seat map library. It will generate an accessible map, legend, handle mouse & keyboard events and finally give you powerful selectors to control your map.
>
> [image: Screenshot of application]

Answer (score 3):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including seating charts.

[Example](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/dashboard/airlinereservation/default.html)

[image: Diagram JS Airline seating map]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available. If you are planning to buy I can suggest below charts which you can customize.

http://www.seatingcharts.com/Demo
[image]

Comment: link is broken can you update it?