# Table seating chart

Tags: library, javascript, planning

I am looking for a JavaScript library that helps build restaurant table seating charts like this:

[image]

<sub>P.S.: i'm not planning to use gojs.</sub>

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript seating chart library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34155/javascript-seating-chart-library)

Comment: @VirtApp: Your goal is to help decide where to put the tables and chairs, right? Or am I misunderstanding, and instead, the table and chairs' positions are already decided, and the software should just help decide what customer goes into what chair?

Comment: Absolutely right  @NicolasRaoul!

Comment: @VirtApp: Then please make it clearer in your question, thanks :-)

Comment: Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and edit your question accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including seating charts.

[Example](https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/5eevjx1z) This example pre-defines all the tables, but the user can also interactively create them.

[image: Diagram JS Restaurant Table]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.