# Drag and drop JavaScript library for restaurant layout

Tags: javascript, angular, floor-plan

I need recommendation for a JavaScript library.

I have to build an interactive restaurant/saloon with tables, zoom out, zoom in (as in google maps) and so on.
I'm more of a "logical" programmer with experience in Databases, Web APIs and I need advice from someone who has already done such things.

The front-end is built on Angular 7 if it matters.

[image: Example table layout]

Comment: You want a browser-side JavaScript library that allows the user to place tables and chairs on a map of a room, right? Should users be able to choose the number and size of the tables/chairs? Do you need something for server-side too?

Comment: Sounds familiar. Check out the [tag:floor-plan] tag, plus [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/table-seating-chart)